# Tableview crashing while running on iOS 5 with xcode 5

Tags: uitableview, ios5, crash, xcode5, sigabrt

When I am trying to run the app on IOS 5 simulator with Xcode 5,its getting crash with following reason.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The NIB data is invalid.'
```

I am using custom cell in UITableview.I have tried everything for cellForRowAtIndexPath method,I have read online.but still its getting crashing.But, Its working fine on IOS 7 and IOS 6 series with Xcode 5. I don't know the exact problem in my UITableview.Anybody can help me out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think You are not connecting the custom cell .xib properly with custom cell sub class(which you have created.). check once.

And make sure all the property that are declared in the custom cell are accessing in the table view cell_for_row_at_index_path  delegate method with appropriate identifier.